# Trying to add updated slideshow to my photography portfolio site, but having issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I used to have a slideshow that only went forward by clicking the image but made a slideshow independently of the site that goes forward and backward by clicking the left or right side of the page. However I am having problems pluggin in the new slideshow to my current website. Maybe you guys could help me out. The photo example above shows how I would like buttons to function[image]

Here is the slideshow that I want

Html

```
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/30.JPG" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/39.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
</div>
<div class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"></div>
<div class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></div>
```

Css:

```
 * {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next and previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}

/* Hide button elements by default */
.prev, .next {
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

/* Show button elements on hover */
.slideshow-container .prev:hover, .slideshow-container .next:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

javascript:

```
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Here is my current site with the slider that only goes forward:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="background_styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <script src="script.js" defer></script>
      <title>The American Southwest Archive Pt.1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-title"><strong><a href='/'>Justin Guthrie</a></strong></div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
          <ul>
            <li ><a href="/">Selected Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="/newworldrites">New World Rites</a></li>
            <li><a href="/shadowboxscultpures">Shadow Box Scultptures</a></li>
            <li class="underline"><a href="/americansouthwest">The American Southwest <br>Archive Pt.1</br></a></a></li>
            <li><a href="/lariverobjects">L.A. River Objects</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Godisalive">God is Alive</a></li>
            <div class="bottom-nav"><strong>
              <li><a href="/about">About / CV</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://shop.justin-guthrie.com/">Shop</a></li>
            </strong>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class='desktop'>
        <div class="slideshow-container">
                      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
                      <div class="slides">
                        <img src="img4/1 ACWA Cover.jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
                        <br><strong>The American Southwest Archive Pt.1</strong>
                        <br>2023
                        <br>Published by B12 Books
                        <br><a href="https://shop.justin-guthrie.com/">Store</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slides">
                        <img src="img4/2 ACWA pages.jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
                      </div>
                      <div class="slides">
                        <img src="img4/3 ACWA pages.jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
                      </div>
                      <div class="slides">
                        <img src="img4/1 .jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
                      </div>
</div>
                
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    float:left;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 25px 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.brand-title {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-links {
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar-links ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.underline{
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

.navbar-links li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.bottom-nav {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bottom-nav li a {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}




.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.desktop{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.description{
        background-color: red;
    display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
}
.slideshow-container {
max-height:80%; 
max-width:80%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    cursor:e-resize;
}

.Paragraphbox {
max-width: 700px;
display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction:column;

}

.slides {
max-height:100%; 
max-width:100%; 

text-align: left;
padding-bottom: 10px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px !important;
}
.slides img{
max-height:100%; 
max-width:100%; 

    text-align: center;
}

.mobile{display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

    
    .brand-title {
        font-size: 3.5em;
        margin-right: 200px;
        margin-left:50px;}
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        width: 90%;
        
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 30px;
        
    }

    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:white;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 30px
        
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        font-size: 3em;
    }

    .navbar-links ul .bottom-nav {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li a {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
    .Paragraphbox {
        max-width: 400px;
        padding-top: 400px;
    }
    .Paragraphbox a {
        color: blue !important;
    }
}
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:black;
    }
    .navbar-links a:hover {
        color: blue !important;
      }

      .slides {
        font-size: 30px;
        }
@media (pointer:none),(pointer:coarse) {


    .brand-title {
        font-size: 3.5em;
        margin-right: 200px;
        margin-left:50px;}
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 30px;
        
    }

    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:white;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        font-size: 3em;
    }

    .navbar-links ul .bottom-nav {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li a {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
    .Paragraphbox {
        max-width: 400px;
        padding-top: 400px;
    }
    .Paragraphbox a {
        color: blue !important;
    }

    .slides {
        font-size: 30px;
        }
}
```

Javascript:

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})

/* Button code */
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var contentbox = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (contentbox.style.display === "block") {
      contentbox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      contentbox.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
/*slide code */

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function pslide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
  if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

I tried to plug in the new slideshow to the current slideshow but the image spans the whole page and will not go forward or backward. I pretty much want my slideshow to look the same as it does currently but have that backwords and forwards button funtionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `<div class="prev">` and `<div class="next">` inside `<div class="mySlides">`. On your code `<body>` is their parent element but when you make `<div class="mySlides">` their parent, it takes dimensions from `<div class="mySlides">`. This is because `width: 45%` means 45% width of parent element. Same goes for height.

See the modified code below:

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next and previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  bottom: 1%;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
}

.prev {
  left: -20%;
}

.next {
  right: -20%;
}


/* Hide button elements by default */

.prev,
.next {
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}


/* Show button elements on hover */

.slideshow-container .prev:hover,
.slideshow-container .next:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/30.JPG" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/39.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <div class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"></div>
  <div class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></div>
</div>
```

Hope you find this useful! Anything else please let me know in comments.